# string is not being written in file - iPhone

Tags: iphone, file-handling

I am using the following code in iPhone to write a string into the file that is stored in my iPhone Project Resource Folder. When i try to read its reading the data successfully but when i try to write its not writing the file although its aloso not giving me any error.

this is my code:

```
NSString *myString; //Assuume the string you want to write is this
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];
[myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Please can anybody guide.

Comment: is there anybody who can help!

Comment: Did you try using `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` method? It returns an error. That can be of help.

Comment: You need to be a bit more patient than expecting an answer after 24 minutes!  Have you tried using writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error to see what error message you are getting back?

Comment: yes i tried. but no success..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The writeToFile:atomically: has been depredecated in iOS 2.0. Use writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error: instead. You should check the content of the string, for example by NSLog() function. Inappropriate initialization can cause a failure.

```
NSLog(@"%@", myString);
[myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: Yes it has the data.. as well.. and i tried using encoding and error its still not writing it to the file...

Comment: I just tested the code from your question with writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:. It works. Do you have a free space on the disk? Are you looking for the file in the right directory?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) testStringReadWrite {
    NSString *myString = @"abcd efgh"; 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];
    CFShow(path);
    NSError *error = nil;

    [myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }


    NSString *readString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
        CFShow(readString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, coming from OS X, I am used to calling `writeToURL()` instead of `writeToFile()`. Turns out, `writeToFile()` is the one that worked for iOS.